# Python program to solve matrix-chain multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, homework, dynamic-programming

An assignment at school required me to write a Python program for this task:

> *In the matrix-chain multiplication problem, we are given a sequence of
>   matrices `A(1), A(2), …, A(n)`. The aim is to compute the product
>   `A(1) …, A(n)` with the minimum number of scalar multiplications.
>   Thus, we have to find an optimal parenthesization of the matrix
>   product `A(1) …, A(n)` such that the cost of computing the product is
>   minimized.*

Here is my solution to this task:

> ```
> def matrix_product(p):
>     """
>     Return m and s.
>
>     m[i][j] is the minimum number of scalar multiplications needed to compute the
>     product of matrices A(i), A(i + 1), ..., A(j).
>
>     s[i][j] is the index of the matrix after which the product is split in an
>     optimal parenthesization of the matrix product.
>
>     p[0... n] is a list such that matrix A(i) has dimensions p[i - 1] x p[i].
>     """
>     length = len(p) # len(p) = number of matrices + 1
>
>     # m[i][j] is the minimum number of multiplications needed to compute the
>     # product of matrices A(i), A(i+1), ..., A(j)
>     # s[i][j] is the matrix after which the product is split in the minimum
>     # number of multiplications needed
>
>     m = [[-1]*length for _ in range(length)]
>     s = [[-1]*length for _ in range(length)]
>
>     matrix_product_helper(p, 1, length - 1, m, s)
>
>     return m, s
>
>
> def matrix_product_helper(p, start, end, m, s):
>
>     """
>     Return the minimum number of scalar multiplications needed to compute the
>     product of matrices A(start), A(start + 1), ..., A(end).
>
>     The minimum number of scalar multiplications needed to compute the
>     product of matrices A(i), A(i + 1), ..., A(j) is stored in m[i][j].
>
>     The index of the matrix after which the above product is split in an optimal
>     parenthesization is stored in s[i][j].
>
>     p[0... n] is a list such that matrix A(i) has dimensions p[i - 1] x p[i].
>     """
>     if m[start][end] >= 0:
>         return m[start][end]
>
>     if start == end:
>         q = 0
>     else:
>         q = float('inf')
>         for k in range(start, end):
>             temp = matrix_product_helper(p, start, k, m, s) \
>                    + matrix_product_helper(p, k + 1, end, m, s) \
>                    + p[start - 1]*p[k]*p[end]
>             if q > temp:
>                 q = temp
>                 s[start][end] = k
>
>     m[start][end] = q
>     return q
>
>
> def print_parenthesization(s, start, end):
>     """
>     Print the optimal parenthesization of the matrix product A(start) x
>     A(start + 1) x ... x A(end).
>
>     s[i][j] is the index of the matrix after which the product is split in an
>     optimal parenthesization of the matrix product.
>     """
>     if start == end:
>         print('A[{}]'.format(start), end='')
>         return
>
>     k = s[start][end]
>
>     print('(', end='')
>     print_parenthesization(s, start, k)
>     print_parenthesization(s, k + 1, end)
>     print(')', end='')
>
>
> n = int(input('Enter number of matrices: '))
> p = []
> for i in range(n):
>     temp = int(input('Enter number of rows in matrix {}: '.format(i + 1)))
>     p.append(temp)
> temp = int(input('Enter number of columns in matrix {}: '.format(n)))
> p.append(temp)
>
> m, s = matrix_product(p)
> print('The number of scalar multiplications needed:', m[1][n])
> print('Optimal parenthesization: ', end='')
> print_parenthesization(s, 1, n)
> ```

Here is an example output:

> ```
> Enter number of matrices: 3
> Enter number of rows in matrix 1: 10
> Enter number of rows in matrix 2: 100
> Enter number of rows in matrix 3: 5
> Enter number of columns in matrix 3: 50
> The number of scalar multiplications needed: 7500
> Optimal parenthesization: ((A[1]A[2])A[3])
> ```

Here is the time taken for this output:

> `0:00:15.332220 seconds`.

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.